# Convert long to int in Java programming

Tags: java

I'm reading 《Effective Java》, and it used (int)(l^(l>>>32)) to convert a long number to int number, but I usually use (int)l to do the same job and it also works very well. I'm wondering if there is a difference between the two methods.Could anyone explain it to me, thanks very much.

Comment: Did you look to see if the book explained why they do it in that manner?

Comment: `l^(l>>>32)` is basically a no-op if the number fits an int. Since all bits >31 will be 0, the XOR will just keep the existing bits [0-31] at their current values (but will flip the sign bit if it's set, so it does something). For numbers that overflow the int type, I get different results from the plain cast and the code you posted, but then, you've overflowed the type already...

Comment: The method in the book is using the same `(int)` cast as you are, but also capturing the upper bits and `XOR`ing them with the lower bits, while zero-shifting down into the leftmost bits.  So the `32` upper bits are shifted down and `XOR`d with the `32` lower bits, and all bits above the 31st are set to zero.

Comment: I have to correct myself; Java stores integer types (e.g. long) in two's complement format; the code in your book assumes sign/magnitude, as did my original comment above. The code in the book doesn't work to convert negative numbers. If you use two's complement, you can just follow the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) to see how the cast works internally.

Comment: @nhgrif:Sorry, I havn't seen that yet.

Comment: @abiessu:Thank you, I got it.

Comment: @vanza:Thank you very much, It's very generous and kind of you to explain so patiently.